# Connect remove server grpc - panic: received message larger than max

Tags: go, ssl, grpc

```
panic: grpc: received message larger than max (577004918 vs. 4194304).
```

I try to connect to a remote grpc server with a key, I get an error in the header.
I need to connect to the server and cover requests with tests
what to do?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "flag"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

var (
    certFile = flag.String("cert", "cer.pem", "A PEM eoncoded certificate file.")
    caFile   = flag.String("CA", "cer.pem", "A PEM eoncoded CA's certificate file.")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    //// Load client cert
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(*certFile, *certFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Load CA cert
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*caFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    // Setup HTTPS client
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
    data :=  `{"device": {"id": "qweqweqe-qweqw-e-qdsad", "app_version": "0", "system_lang": "ru", "os": 1, "timezone": "Europe/Moscow"}
}`
    
    req, err := http.NewRequest(
        "POST", "https://url/*****.*****.*****.v1.SessionAPI/Register", strings.NewReader(data),
    )
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/grpc")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    panic(resp.Header.Get("grpc-message"))
}
```

Comment: The error is valid. gRPC individual message sizes cannot exceed 4MB. If your message payloads will be this large, you'll need to chunk the data and send a stream of chunk messages.

Comment: @colm.anseo I am not sending data more than 4MB

Comment: @colm.anseo 
body content is visible in code